How to integrate $\int\frac{|x+3|+|x-7|}{|x-2|-|x+4|}dx ?$
How to integrate $$\int\frac{|x+3|+|x-7|}{|x-2|-|x+4|}dx$$ ?
My tuition student asked me about this integral. Also, he asked this integral to one of the Professors of IISc(Indian Institute of Science) Bengaluru. The professor's way of Approach is mentioned here:

My tuition student was thinking of taking intervals like $(-\infty,-4);(-4,-3);(-3,2);(2,7)$ and then integrating by taking functions of different limits.
The Professor told him to try by directly taking the limit $(-\infty,x)$ .
But I think both are wrong. Let me explain why ?
The given integral is $\int\frac{|x+3|+|x-7|}{|x-2|-|x+4|}dx$
Now I will apply one trick .
I will multiply the numerator and denominator by $(|x-2|+|x+4|)$
The integral will become:
\begin{align*}\int\frac{(|x+3|+|x-7|)(|x-2|+|x+4|)}{|x-2|^{2}-|x+4|^{2}}dx&=\int\frac{(|x+3|+|x-7|)(|x-2|+|x+4|)}{(x-2)^{2}-(x+4)^{2}}dx\\&=\int\frac{(|x+3|+|x-7|)(|x-2|+|x+4|)}{-12(x+1)}dx\end{align*}
Now I think a student can integrate by writing $|x+3|=(x+3)\mathrm{sgn}(x+3)$ ; $|x-7|=(x-7)\mathrm{sgn}(x-7)$ ; etc...
The main thing that is to be noted here is $\mathrm{sgn}(x+3)$ is constant. Similarly $\mathrm{sgn}(x-7)$ is also constant. So, I think one can integrate easily after this step.
Please inform me whether I am correct or not.
Regards
JNU

The function $\text{sgn}(x + 3)$ is not constant. It outputs values in ${-1,0,1}$ but the value depends on the choice of $x$. The correct method is to consider separate regions, like your student did. Also, I don't think the question is well posed as an indefinite integral. It seems like you are anyway interested in the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $a$ for some real $a$.

@sudeep5221, yes of course but the value of $sgn(x+3)$ will depend on intervals. For the interval $(-4,-3)$ , $sgn(x+3)=-1$. Like this.

Wolfram Alpha and Geogebra are giving examples in terms of signum function.

Please inform me whether I am correct or not?

You should listen to your student, and work on the 5 regions sequentially.

Ok. @Paul. I have understood

Seems the professor meant finding a piecewise function by integrating on $(-\infty, x)$

@DS, maybe, but the integral won't converge, no?

This easiest way would be to integrate the five regions separately.  Integrating the five regions separately is valid and will work.  And is easy.  Can't think of any reason doing it any other way would be desirable. "The main thing that is to be noted here is sgn(x+3) is constant. Similarly sgn(x−7) is also constant."  HUH????? No they aren't! (the are constant within each of the five regions which makes integrating the STILL breaking into regions)

The primitives of $f$ will depend of the interval on which you are integrating. What you can do is remove the absolute values by "playing" with $x$ :
$$
\frac{|x+3|+|x-7|}{|x-2|-|x+4|}=
\begin{cases}
  \frac{-2x+4}{6}~\text{if $x \in \mathopen{]}-\infty,-4\mathclose{[}$} \\
  \frac{-2x+4}{-2x-2}~\text{if $x \in [-4,-3\mathclose{[}$} \\
  \frac{10}{-2x-2}~\text{if $x \in [-3,-1\mathclose{[} \cup \mathopen{]}-1,2[$} \\
  \frac{10}{-6}~\text{if $x \in [2,7\mathclose{[}$} \\
 \frac{2x-4}{-6}~\text{if $x \in [7,+\infty\mathclose{[}$} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Next step is just integrating each component of the piecewise function.
NB : You can create primitives that are fully defined on $]-\infty , -1 [$ and $[2 , + \infty [$ if you "play" with the constants $c_i$ (cf. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpmgwm8s4c)
